Freertos wait two event in a task
I'm using 2xDMA to start ADC and get raw value in a task. After completed two DMA, I need to process these data in same task. I'm thinking of using two xTaskNotify in each callback but I'm not sure how to wait them in one line code. Is it possible with using tasknofity? Or, should I use another method?

If you want to wait for two events in one line code, you can try to use FreeRTOS Event Group Bits.
You can assign DMA Channel complete state for each bit. So you can wait any
combination of completed DMA Channels.
#define DMA_1_CHANNEL   ( 1 << 0 )
#define DMA_2_CHANNEL   ( 1 << 1 )

static EventGroupHandle_t dma_channel_cplt_evt_bit_handle = NULL;

void dma1_irq() {
    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
    xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR(dma_channel_cplt_evt_bit_handle, DMA_1_CHANNEL, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
    
    if( xResult != pdFAIL )
    {
        portYIELD_FROM_ISR( xHigherPriorityTaskWoken );
    }
}

// same irq handler for second dma

Init event group bits
dma_channel_cplt_evt_bit_handle = xEventGroupCreate();
if (dma_channel_cplt_evt_bit_handle != NULL) {
   xEventGroupClearBits(dma_channel_cplt_evt_bit_handle, DMA_1_CHANNEL | DMA_2_CHANNEL);
} else {
    // Error creating event group bits
}

Waiting for two bits in task code
void task_code(void *ptr_args) {
    while (true) {

        EventBits_t uxBits = xEventGroupWaitBits(
                                dma_channel_cplt_evt_bit_handle,
                                DMA_1_CHANNEL | DMA_2_CHANNEL,
                                pdTRUE,
                                pdTRUE,
                                portMAX_DELAY);
        if ((uxBits & (DMA_1_CHANNEL | DMA_2_CHANNEL)) == (DMA_1_CHANNEL | DMA_2_CHANNEL)) {
            // execute code after all dma complete
            // ...
        }
    }
}


For better responsiveness and leaner implementation using task notifications as event group could be a better approach. See https://www.freertos.org/RTOS_Task_Notification_As_Event_Group.html. Note that signaling an event group from ISR is internally deferred to the timer task, which does the rest of the signaling action.
